# Android App name conflict

Tags: android

I am about to launch an android app and I have decided the name "Math addict" for it.

The problem is -

1. There is a website named mathaddict.com which has their software called Math addict but I couldn't find copyright documents on their website.
2. An app exists on Apple App store with the exact same name.

But there is no app with such name on Google Play as of now. Moreover I haven't copied anything from any lf these apps/softwares.

Is it advisable to use this name for my app? My apps have been suspended on Google Play in the past and hence I am little more apprensive this time.

Please suggest what can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IANAL. As long as you are not trying to impersonate these other products, you should be fine. However, in the extreme case this can quickly lead to some ugly court battles if your app is in competition with these other websites and products. Assuming that you are a single developer, you probably don't have to worry about this. However, if you have a large success, then you might need to be concerned. The legal battles between Apple Computers and Apple Music are quite famous for fighting over the legal right to a name.

I really don't think you need to be worried about the legalities here. On the other hand, you want your app to be found and not to be confused with other similar apps. At this point, I think differentiating yourself from the competition is probably a much higher concern.

Answer (score 2):

I also suggest you jse a different name, let's assume someone search's Math addict in google it is highly possible that the web site you mentionned and the app from app store will be shown at first so yours will be the last except if you do some good work on keywords optimisation,
You instead use something like Math addict app , mathapp, appmath

Answer (score 1):

According to Google Play policy:

> Impersonation or Deceptive Behavior: Don't pretend to be someone else,
>   and don't represent that your app is authorized by or produced by
>   another company or organization if that is not the case. Products or
>   the ads they contain also must not mimic functionality or warnings
>   from the operating system or other apps. Products must not contain
>   false or misleading information in any content, title, icon,
>   description, or screenshots. Developers must not divert users or
>   provide links to any other site that mimics or passes itself off as
>   another app or service. Apps must not have names or icons that appear
>   confusingly similar to existing products, or to apps supplied with the
>   device (such as Camera, Gallery or Messaging).

[Source](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)

So I will highly suggest you to select a different name for safety.

Comment: Anyway, the name can be changed later, the package cannot.

Comment: Using the same name doesn't necessarily qualify as "Impersonation or deceptive behavior"

Comment: What do you suggest? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @fida1989 - Which rule is being violated by me?

Comment: @RushilSablania: You didn't yet. But Google may flag or 3rd party may file complaint for using same name. Read the last line in the quoted paragraph in my answer.